# Performance Multiple inserts or multiple values single insert

Tags: mysql, performance, insert

Performance wise (times and server load) is it better to have multiple inserts or single insert with multiple values.

I've found here on stackoverflow we can have up to 1000 value sets per insert.

I'm talking about 2 types of situations ...

- about 1000-3000 values to insert
- sometimes I'll have between 20000-30000 value sets to inser in a mySQL DB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, generally bulk insertion is faster than single insert at a time as it avoids intermediate communication which was occurring for every insert statement.

But sometimes it leads to problems as insert/update statements acquire exclusive locks on tables/rows which means no other process/connection can use table at that time.

If you have multiple processes using DB at the same  some of which are reading from table and some are writing then whole operations will be locked/stopped at the time of your bulk insertion

so bulk insertion will lock the table for more time than single insert which can cause issues for other processes if lock time is more and DB is not tuned for it.

If you are just inserting into the DB with no other operation, then go for bulk insert from a file (which is much faster) and if you have other processes in place adjust bulk insert frequency considering locking.

Possible duplicate is of update statements [Is bulk update faster than single update in db2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068743/is-bulk-update-faster-than-single-update-in-db2)

Answer (score 1):

As it always with performance the correct answer is **it depends** because there are a lot more factors that you mentioned.

But generally speaking multiple-row insert statements are faster than individual single-row inserts because of the lower communication overhead between the client and server.

Recommended reading

- [Speed of INSERT Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-speed.html)